# without using function how to call result set to another stored procedure in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

i am working on sql server 2008
i have a stored procedure for getting total amount.  while executing this i am getting result

my first stored procedure like this:

```
  alter procedure [dbo].[jaseem_test4]
@carid varchar(50)
as
begin
Declare
@locid integer,
@vtid integer,
@day varchar(20),
@Date date,
@startdate datetime,
@Pdatetime datetime,@Ptime time,
@prkdtime datetime,@pdate date,
 @Starttime time,@startloctime varchar(10),
 @currenttime varchar(10),@endtime time,
 @endloctime varchar(10)
 --finding loc_id and vtid
 set @locid = (select t.locid 
 from Transaction_tbl t where Tbarcode=@carid)
 set @vtid=(select t.vtid from Transaction_tbl t where TBarcode=@carid)
 ----------
 --finding parked time
 set @Pdatetime=(select t.dtime from Transaction_tbl t where Tbarcode=@carid)
 --finding location end time
select @endtime=l.EndTime from Location_tbl l where l.Locid=@locid 


  select @endloctime=convert(Varchar(8), @endtime,108)
  select @currenttime=CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),GETDATE(),108)
  select @Date=convert(date,getdate())
  select @pdate=convert(date,@Pdatetime,108)
   select @Ptime=CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),@Pdatetime,108)
  declare @prevousdate datetime
  select @prevousdate=convert(date,getdate()-1)
  declare @LT integer

 if @endloctime<@Ptime
  begin
   select @startdate= cast(@Date as Datetime) + cast(@endloctime as Datetime)
   select @prkdtime=cast(@prevousdate as Datetime) + cast(@Ptime as Datetime)
 select @LT =datediff(mi,@prkdtime,@startdate)
--select @LT as LT1
end
else
begin
select @LT=datediff(mi,@ptime,@endloctime)
--select @LT as LT
end

declare @PT integer=datediff(mi,@Pdatetime,getdate())
--select @PT as PT

DEclare @daycount integer
if (@LT >= @PT)
begin
set @daycount=1
--select @daycount


end
If (@PT > @LT) 
begin
Declare @q  Integer ,@q1 float,@modvAL float,@PT1 integer
          set @q=1
   set @modvAL=1440
  set @PT1=@PT-@LT
 -- select @PT1 as PT1
  if @PT1>@modvAL
  begin
  set @q1= round((@PT1) / (@modvAL),0)
  --select @q1 as q2
  end
  else
  begin
  set @q1=1 
  end
  set @q=(@q+@q1)
  set @daycount=@daycount*@q
  --select @daycount as daycount
 end

 ------------------------------------------------------


 declare @days integer,@s varchar(10),@Total integer,
 @n integer
 ,@day1 integer,
 @checkWeekend integer,
@Hamount integer,
 @Htotel integer, @Namount integer,@startloctime1 varchar(10),@currenttime1 varchar(10),
 @Ntotal integer
set @days=0
set @n=0
set @day1=@daycount
set @Htotel=0
set @Ntotal=0

  Select @startloctime1= convert(Varchar(8),( select l.StartTime   from Location_tbl l where l.Locid=5),108)
select @currenttime1=CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),GETDATE(),108)

while (@days < @day1)
begin
if @day1=1
begin

if @startloctime1>@currenttime1
begin
set @s= datename(dw,getdate()-1)
end
else
begin
set @s= datename(dw,getdate())
end
end
else
begin
select @s=datename(dw,getdate()-@n)
--select @s
end
select @checkWeekend=   Weekend from weekends_tbl where weekdays=@s  
if @checkWeekend=1
begin

select @hamount= Hamount  from locvtypeassign_tbl where 
vtid=@vtid and locid=@locid and active=0

set @Htotel=@Htotel+@Hamount

end
else
begin

select @Namount= NAmount  from locvtypeassign_tbl where 
vtid=@vtid and locid=@locid and active=0
set @Ntotal=@Ntotal+ @Namount
end
set @days=@days+1
set @n= @n+1
set @Total= @Htotel+@Ntotal

end
select @Total as [Total]

  end --End main
   Go
```

---

if i pass carid i am getting out put like this:

```
Total
100
```

only for getting this i wrote a stored procedure around 100 lines .in this stored procedure i am just passing one value(Tbarcode)

i have a another stored procedure somthing line this:

```
Select t.dtime,t.vtid,t.locid
   from transaction_tbl t where Tbarcode='4502'
```

my out put is something like this:

```
dtime                          vtid        locid
-----------------------    ----------- -----------
2014-10-02 23:43:39.453           7           5
```

i want to add this two stored procedure and i am expecting out put

```
   dtime                          vtid        locid       Totalamount
    -----------------------    ----------- -----------    ------------
    2014-10-02 23:43:39.453           7           5        100
```

i know this i can do by making first stored procedure as function,and return the total amount to second stored procedure.but i fear about execution speed.
if i call function in my stored procedure then my stored procedure execution will get slow right?
without using function is therey any way to get my stored procedure result into second stored proceure??
any help is very appriciable

**how i can call my first stored procedure result to seconde stored procedure??**

Comment: Without your procedure code, it's hard to comment anything.

Comment: you need my first stored procedure code?

Answer (score 0):

Simplest thing you can do is; call your main stored procedure passing the `Totalamount` value and then display the result like

Main procedure body

```
exec sp_another_proc 100
```

In `sp_another_proc`

```
create procedure sp_another_proc (@total int)
as
begin
Select t.dtime,
       t.vtid,
       t.locid,
       @total as TotalAmount
   from transaction_tbl t where Tbarcode='4502'
end
```

**EDIT:**

In your first procedure `[dbo].[jaseem_test4]` instead of the last line

```
select @Total as [Total]
```

Call the second procedure like

```
exec my_second_procedure @Total
```

Modify your second procedure to accept a `Integer` parameter as shown above and then just display it.

Comment: can u elabruatete your explnation please

Comment: in this time how this stored procedure get @total value

Comment: sir how i can call my first stored procedure result to seconde stored procedure

Answer (score 0):

I would use a similar approach as Rahul, but slightly different. To make sure you don't break your existing code which might already be using these 2 procedures, I would do the following:

Step 1. - Extend the first procedure with an optional output parameter as follows (see comments at the end of the lines I've added):

```
alter procedure [dbo].[jaseem_test4]
@carid varchar(50),
@totalAmount int = null OUTPUT  /* the new output parameter which returns the total value */
as
begin
....

set @totalAmount = @Total  /* setting the output parameter to the return total value */
select @Total as [Total]

end --End main
Go
```

Step 2 - call the first procedure with the output parameter from the 2nd procedure - I've borrowed Rahul's code for this

Please note that you just have to add to your 2nd procedure only the lines with a comment:

```
create procedure sp_another_proc
as
begin

...
declare @totalAmount int  /* the total amount variable */
exec jaseem_test4 'InputCaridValue', @totalAmount OUT /* call procedure to get total amount */
....

Select t.dtime,
   t.vtid,
   t.locid,
   @totalAmount as TotalAmount  /* add to your final select the @totalAmount variable */
  from transaction_tbl t where Tbarcode='4502'
end

GO
```

All should work just fine.

Comment: this method isn't bad (OUTPUT param is good), but only works if another change is made to the original `jaseem_test4` proc. At the end of that proc, the `select @Total as [Total]` needs to be wrapped in an `IF` condition else that result will be in the set of result sets. Without adding a new input param, you could use the @totalAmount output param to also pass a value into as a "trigger" of sorts. Meaning, wrap the final `SELECT` in `IF (@totalAmount IS NULL) BEGIN SELECT ... END;`. Then in `sp_another_proc`, add `SET @totalAmount = 0;` between the `DECLARE ` and the `EXEC`.

Answer (score 0):

One approach, assuming that the second procedure also only returns a single row, is to create a 3rd procedure that will call both of the existing ones, capture the output of each, and then select the combination for the real output. The benefit here is that you don't have to modify, in any way, the two existing procedures. This is quite helpful if either, or both, of those existing stored procedures are called by another code and hence a change in behavior might have adverse effects, or at the very least it would create additional complication and code paths to test for.

For example:

```sql
DECLARE @JaseemTest4Result TABLE (TotalAmount INT);
DECLARE @Proc2Result TABLE (dtime DATETIME, vtid INT, locid INT);

INSERT INTO @JaseemTest4Result (TotalAmount)
   EXEC jaseem_test4 @carid = 25;

INSERT INTO @Proc2Result (dtime, vtid, locid)
   EXEC proc2 @Tbarcode = '4502';

SELECT p2r.dtime, p2r.vtid, p2r.locid, jt4.TotalAmount
FROM   @JaseemTest4Result jt4
CROSS JOIN  @Proc2Result p2r;
```

Or, if the second stored proc is only for this purpose, you can update it to do only the part from the example above that captures the `TotalAmount` and then JOIN the real table and the table variable together:

```sql
DECLARE @JaseemTest4Result TABLE (TotalAmount INT);

INSERT INTO @JaseemTest4Result (TotalAmount)
   EXEC jaseem_test4 @carid = 25;

Select t.dtime, t.vtid, t.locid, jt4.TotalAmount
from transaction_tbl t
CROSS JOIN @JaseemTest4Result jt4
where t.Tbarcode='4502'
```